# xmlhttp-readystate=0 after 40 requests

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Here is my code, I want to upload 8000 users, after 40 uploads to //serever/userup.php it fails by readystate=0 error

```
var xhttp;
   sendReq(i);

   function sendReq(i)
   {
      var cellcount = columns.length;

      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //console.log(jsondata[i][columns[1]]);



        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //console.log(this.responseText);
            console.log('sent '+i);

                if (i<rowcount) 
                { 
                    i++;
                    sendReq(i)
                }         
          }
          else
          {
            console.log('error');
          }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "https://server/userup.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("region="+loggedRegion+"&campname="+camptitle+"&campid="+cid+"&custcode="+jsondata[i][columns[0]]+"&custname="+jsondata[i][columns[1]]+"&custmob="+jsondata[i][columns[2]]+"&custnation="+jsondata[i][columns[3]]+"&custarea="+jsondata[i][columns[4]]); 
}
```

Is there any solution for wait until readystate changed to 4 and resume the upload?

Comment: You want to upload 8000 users through ajax requests?! Surely there's a better way to handle that rather than firing off 8000 ajax calls

Comment: You already are waiting for readyState 4 before continuing as far as we can see. If you do get back a response from the servers that not okay, you whole loop ends. Anyway, if you have access to the database here and you don't regularly need to add 8000 things to it, why not do it directly instead of like this? Your  server might not even like all the back and forth and stop you after a while...

Comment: If any better ways to do that,let me know, thanks in advance.